# How To Mute "DING" Sound When User Click Outside Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-interop

I'm showing a form using `Form.ShowDialog()`, in this Form I have override `void WndProc(ref Message m)` because I want to close this form when user click outside Form area.

```
    private const int WM_NCACTIVATE = 0x0086;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_NCACTIVATE:
                if (_canClose) // when user click outside form, close form
                    this.Close(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

This code work as I expected, but one minor problem, Windows play `DING` sound every time user click outside Form area, I want to "mute" this `DING` when this code processed.

### `UPDATE`

I managed to make this Form work as I want to, using advice from `Hassan Mujtaba`, but I still wonder how to mute this `DING` if I use `Form.ShowDialog`.

[image: DateRange Control]

Comment: Not sure if it would help - have you tried getting rid of the `base.WndProc` call in that case?  To do that you'd add a `return` inside the `if` after `this.Close`

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham, I have try that before, but still same.

Comment: It is the mouse click that dingalings you.  Tough to fix, it was posted to the window that was clicked, not your dialog.  Pinvoking EnableWindow() on the other windows in your app is an ugly fix.

Comment: @HansPassant, can you point me some resource on that subject ? I'm not familiar with Windows development other than .NET.

Comment: Same place you found WM_NCACTIVATE.  The MSDN Library too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Form.Show() instead of Form.ShowDialog() will solve the problem.